# How to prove that if $\sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(k(x)/k)\Leftrightarrow \sigma(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

$k(x)$ is the rational function field in one variable over $k$, and $a,b,c,d\in k$ such that $ad-bc\neq 0$.

I know that $\operatorname{Gal}(k(x)/k)=\{\varphi:k(x)\to k(x)|\varphi$ is a ring morphism and $\varphi|_{k}=Id_k \}$.
But if $\sigma(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ then $\sigma(0)=\frac{b}{d}\neq 0$ i.e. $\sigma|_k\neq Id_k$.

Is it right, or what is wrong?

Comment: The automorphism is $\sigma(f(x)) = f(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})$

Comment: Can you prove this is a subset of the Galois group?

Comment: $\phi$ is a ring isomorphism, not just a homomorphism.

Comment: How do you get $\sigma(0)=\frac{b}{d}?$ That misunderstands how the ring of rational functions works. $0$ in the ring is the constant rational function, which is $0$ no matter what the value of $x$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $\sigma(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is only supposed to tell you directly what $\sigma$ does to one particular element of $k(x)$, namely $x$ itself, not what it does to other elements like $0\in k(x)$. For example, say we consider $\mathbb{Q}(e)/\mathbb{Q}$. The equation $\sigma(e)=e+1$ is just a single equation, it doesn't tell you directly what $\sigma(0)$ is. It doesn't make any sense to "evaluate" $2.71828\dots$ to $0$.

You can however *indirectly* determine what $\sigma$ does to any element of $k(x)$ using the knowledge of $\sigma(x)$ and the fact $\sigma$ is a field automorphism. Since any element of $k(x)$ is built from scalars of $k$ and $x$ using the basic arithmetic operations, and $\sigma$ preserves these scalars and operations, we can say if $f(x)$ is any rational expression in $x$ (an element of $k(x)$) then $\sigma(f(x))$ must equal $f(\sigma(x))$. For example, if $\sigma(x)=x+1$ then $\sigma(x^2-1)=\sigma(x)^2-1=(x+1)^2-1$ and $\sigma(0)=0$.